# Extract common commands into functions

Tags: bash, function, kubernetes, configmap

I've got a file that consists of a number of configmaps.

Something like

```
{{- define "config1" -}}
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-{{.Chart.Nn}}
apiVersion: v1
data:
  script.sh: |-
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "Hello World"
    echo "Hello Planet"
{{- end -}}
```

How do I extract **echo "Hello World"** and **echo "Hello Planet"** into a function so I can simply refer to the function within **script.sh** for the configmaps that need to run these particular commands?

I'm trying to avoid having to write the same code over and over.
Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, you mean a function in the helm template? or just a function in Kubernetes?

Comment: Either way really. 

The goal is just to have a function/code-block I can call multiple times within my script, instead of rewriting it for each configmap.